# Cookie expiration time

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am after some help with my javascript code. I am afraid I have no experience with JS, only html and css. I have a cookie policy notice on my website that I have installed from a friend. I am wondering if someone can tell me the expiration date I currently have in my code (as I have no clue)..
Also if someone could recommend an expiration time for the EU Cookie Law policy if my code isn't appropriate already?

Code Below:

```
var euCookie = {
    g: function(){
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf("euCookieLaw") == 0) return c.substring("euCookieLaw".length,c.length);
        }

        return null;
    },
    s: function(value){
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+315532800000);

        document.cookie = "euCookieLaw="+value+"; expires="+date.toGMTString()+"; path=/";
    }
```

Comment: To see the cookie expiration date, use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ro/firefox/addon/firebug/). You can [see the cookies](https://getfirebug.com/cookies) in real-time.

Comment: You could also use `console.log(date.toGMTString())` after `date.setTime(date.getTime()+315532800000);` to see the result in Firebug console. Anyway, the result was `Sun, 20 Aug 2023 12:22:04 GMT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code sets the cookie to expire 315532800000 milliseconds from now, i.e. that resolves to 3652 days or just about 10 years into the future.

Comment: I see, so that value is from this date + the number in milliseconds! Thank you for your help! simple enough.. :) learning!